# Notification Center is not working in collectionView DidSelect in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, notificationcenter

I am trying to receive data from notification addObserve. But observer does not receive any data. Posting data from collectionView DidSelect and receiving from another UIViewController. it does not called.

Here is my code:

```
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let imageDataDict:[String: Any] = ["image": self.setTabData[id]]
        print("image dict index::::", imageDataDict)
        
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("dynamicIndex"), object: nil, userInfo: imageDataDict)
     }
```

Receiver end UIViewController I have added this code

Add this in ViewDidload

```
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.dynamicViewIndex(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("dynamicIndex"), object: nil)
```

Notification center observer objc function

```
    @objc func dynamicViewIndex(notification: NSNotification) {
         // handling code

         print("dynamic index value observered", notification)



        if let dict = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary? {


            if let ValueID = dict["image"] as? UInt {

                print("UInt index val:::", ValueID)

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Any help much appreciated please...

Answer (score 1):

For this method

```
@objc func dynamicViewIndex(notification: NSNotification) {
```

to be called the vc that contains it must be shown/active when the collection's didSet is triggered and if it isn't shown/active then the correct pattern is to use segue/delegate

Comment: Actually the view active and shown. But still it does not receive any data from observer

Comment: Add a break point inside beginning of `dynamicViewIndex`  ?

Comment: In break point post message triggered but in receiver end add observer is not triggered

Comment: if you can share a github demo of the problem ?